# In Android project, Why It is fail to mark the location whose latitude and longitude are got from other classes

Tags: android, google-maps

it is fail to mark LOCATION2 on map , but is successful if replace it using LOCATION1.

```
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng LOCATION1 = new LatLng(18.79038, 98.98468);
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION1, 13));
        vehicles=query.QueryVhe();
        Double lat=vehicles.get(0).getLatitude(); //get latitude.
        Double lng=vehicles.get(0).getLongitude();//get Longitude.

        //I am sure that lat and lng have already got data here.
        //here is a problem that it is fail to mark LOCATION2.
        LatLng LOCATION2 = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Sydney")
                .snippet("Chaing Mai.")
                .position(LOCATION2));// But if it is successful if LOCATION2 were LOCATION1.
    }
}
```

Comment: From where you will get the (lat,lng) value for LOCATION2?

Comment: Througth this way :Query query=new Query();
    List<Vehicles> vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicles>(); and the Query is a class to get data from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code
if it helps you please make it as right

```
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title("My Location")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.myloc))
                        .anchor(0.0f, 1.0f) // Anchors the marker on the bottom left
                        .position(new LatLng(lat, lon)))
                        .setDraggable(true);
```

if you dont need anchor or setdraggable you can remove it

Comment: latlng value can not be predefined... when marker is creating that time only new latlng value you have to give ,by using new LatLng(lat,lng),you cant use LatLng variable here directly.

Comment: It also not work using new LatLng(lat,lng),just work for data like this constant:lat=37.7750,lng=122.4183.But I am  sure that  my lat and lng have got data through debugging.

Answer (score 2):

You can add your marker in following manner.

```
    Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
           .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183)) // those are dummy values for lat and long
           .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.location))
           .title("My Location on Map")
           .snippet("details"));
```